# Multiple Websites and PHP Versions with Docker-Compose

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

At the moment I'm building my own dev environment because I want to get rid of MAMP.

I created a docker-compose file with a nginx proxy and it's basically working. My problem is, that several old php projects require different php versions.

Here is how far I already got with my compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  project1:
    build: ./config/5.3.29/nginx/
    container_name: project1
    volumes:
        - ./project1/:/var/www/html
    links:
        - php-5.3.29:php        
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=project1.org"
    expose:
      - "8080"

  project2:
    build: ./config/5.6/nginx/
    container_name: project2
    volumes:
        - ./project2/:/var/www/html
    links:
        - php-5.6:php       
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=project2.de"
    expose:
      - "8081"

  php-5.3.29:
    build: ./config/5.3.29/php/
    container_name: php-5.3.29
    ports:
        - 9000:9000

  php-5.6:
    build: ./config/5.6/php/
    container_name: php-5.6
    ports:
        - 9001:9000
```

As you can see, I have two projects. The PHP containers require to volume from the the same path as the project does. Is there a way to generate the path dynamically? Project 3 will also use php 5.6.

Or am I using the wrong way to go in general? In the end there will be around 10 Magento online shops.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Common question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031943/running-multiple-dockerize-projects-at-the-same-time-using-php-mysql-nginx

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer!

Today I was able to solve my problem with this docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./config/nginx/
    container_name: nginx
    volumes_from:
        - www_data
    links:
        - php-5.3.29
        - php-5.5
    ports:
      - 80:80

  php-5.3.29:
    build: ./config/5.3.29/
    container_name: php-5.3.29
    volumes_from:
        - www_data

  php-5.5:
    build: ./config/5.5/
    container_name: php-5.5
    volumes_from:
        - www_data

  php-5.6:
    build: ./config/5.6/
    container_name: php-5.6
    volumes_from:
        - www_data

  www_data:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

I removed the proxy and used the nginx config to handle the different websites. Then I was able to include the different php versions like this:

```
fastcgi_pass php-5.5:9000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference directories above the compose file like `../sites:/var/www/html` or similar. Not sure when you say "dynamically" if you need additional logic to generate the paths.

In general it seems like your naming is a bit too specific, which might be fine for an initial workstation, but as things start to change, it's going to be harder to maintain.